# Output json only using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, web-services

I'm making web service application using rails. I use rails inbuilt script to do the most of things

this is what i used

first i make new project using   `rails new anyname`

then i create model  and view using  `rails generate scaffold test2 name:string age:integer.....`

and finally I migrate data to the sqllite3 database using `rake db:migrate`

steps going smoothly and didn't get any errors

after this i run `rails s` to start web server and web application runs fine in my localhost. all the scaffolding are auto generated textboxes,forms

but i want to output this only to JSOS format (as a pure web service).I read many tutorials and do many things. marked output as a json and so on.but no luck

can someone please tell me how can i output JSON only ?or give me a good tutorial to implementing JSON web service using rails. I'm new to rails and I don't have much knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard `scaffold` generated, it should work out-of-the-box. Let's just append ".json" to your URL.

For sake of example - if you generate'd scaffold of `user` -

```
rails g scaffold user name
```

the url generated would be "/users" for your `index` action. If you append the url with ".json" - "/users.json", it will return JSON as expected.

Comment: Yes It works :) thanks sir. and could you please tell me is there any way to nicely arrange JSON. like xml viewing on the browser ? my JSON shows messy results, no line separation. Im not consume this JSON service anywhere. I only want  to show it as JSON. thanks

Comment: Actually I'm afraid this is the case. JSON generated from your Rails application is meant to be consumed by other applications, so it is stripped with all unnecessary white spaces (when consuming - computers don't care about readability). Bu, you can install a plugin to web browser to easier read through the generated JSON - check Chrome extension like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en Good luck!

Comment: Thanks sir. I made this web service for my university project they only need a web service implemented. not consume . I already built another two web service using asp.net and PHP but with xml.  I'm newbie to rails that why I asking sir  :) and. thank you very much for providing me this useful information

Comment: I hope you enjoy Ruby and Rails then! Wish you good luck with your University project!